# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for date picker bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to use datepicker of **bootstrap** ,what I use this code I got error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Create:283
(anonymous function) Create:283
n.Callbacks.j jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
n.Callbacks.k.fireWith jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
n.extend.ready
```

In this code which having the error,I took it from bootstrap site as-is...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker4').datepicker({
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is the Div

```
<div class="well">
    <div id="datetimepicker4" class="input-append">
        <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text" />
        <span class="add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
            </i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the libaray which I use and it doesnt help.
I try to add them one by one to see if this problem is solving but not ,any clue?

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>   
<script src="~/Scripts/moment-datepicker.js"></script>          
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />        
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/moment-datepicker/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 



<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/Create.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your trying to attach the datepicker to a div tag. Add `id="datetimepicker4"` to the input (and remove it from the div)

Comment: @StephenMuecke-Hi,not sure that I got you can you please show me what do you mean?

Comment: @StephenMuecke-do you mean like this <i data-time-icon="icon-time" id="datetimepicker4" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"> ,this is not working either...and also like this <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text" id="datetimepicker4" /> dosnt work

Comment: Have just realized you are doing this as a component, in which case I think you need `<div id="datetimepicker4" class="input-append date">` (note "date").  The alternative is use as a field in which case the id is applied to the input as in `<input id="datetimepicker4 data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text" />`

Comment: @StephenMuecke-not sure that I got you can you please put it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding class `date` to the `<div>` tag

```
<div class="well">
  <div class="input-append date"> // additional class name
    <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text" id="datetimepicker4" />
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

From the documentation

> Adding the date class to an input-append or input-prepend bootstrap
>   component will allow the add-on elements to trigger the picker.

Answer (score 4):

Had same problem, in my case it was fact taht I have included
bootstrap-datepicker.js  earlier than bootstrap.min.js . 
After moving bootstrap-datepicker.js  to footer - everything goes fine.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="input-append">
        <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text" id="datetimepicker4" />
        <span class="add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
            </i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

that should do the trick.